# PostgreSQL - Cross Schema Foreign Keys - permission denied for table

Tags: postgresql

I've created a new table called **device**, in a schema called **51025**.

I'm now trying to add the following constraint on the table.

```
ALTER TABLE "51025".device ADD CONSTRAINT device_solution_fk FOREIGN KEY (solution_id)
        REFERENCES public.solution (solution_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

But it fails with this error.

> ERROR:  permission denied for table solution SQL state: 42501

I know the issue is being caused by the fact the table I'm referencing is in a different schema but I'm not experienced with PostgreSQL, so my knowledge is very small.

Any thoughts on this?

**Edit**: I'm using PostgreSQL 14.6

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the following information gathered using `psql`: 1) `SELECT current_user;` 2) `\du` 3) `\dn+ public` 4) `\z public.solution`